# Extract data from firmware (.bin) file which is compressed or encrypted

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware

I have a firmware image of LCD TV that I want to research. Basically I want to customize RGB color settings (from source code), Logo of TV ... Is it possible? I `binwalk` to scan the file.

```
binwalk RDA_533.bin



 DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

No result :(

```
binwalk -E RDA_533.bin



 DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     ENTROPY
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 4096          0x1000          Rising entropy edge (0.950169)
 12288         0x3000          Rising entropy edge (0.950685)
 65536         0x10000         Falling entropy edge (0.794250)
 73728         0x12000         Rising entropy edge (0.984550)
 557056        0x88000         Falling entropy edge (0.789475)
 561152        0x89000         Rising entropy edge (0.994484)
 4317184       0x41E000        Falling entropy edge (0.717537)
 4321280       0x41F000        Rising entropy edge (0.993817)
 4337664       0x423000        Falling entropy edge (0.831574)
 4341760       0x424000        Rising entropy edge (0.969480)
 4358144       0x428000        Rising entropy edge (0.951280)
 4362240       0x429000        Falling entropy edge (0.841719)
 4366336       0x42A000        Rising entropy edge (0.986001)
 4370432       0x42B000        Falling entropy edge (0.845293)
 4374528       0x42C000        Rising entropy edge (0.975581)
 4407296       0x434000        Rising entropy edge (0.989225)
 4427776       0x439000        Rising entropy edge (0.994871)
 4460544       0x441000        Falling entropy edge (0.638917)
 7327744       0x6FD000        Rising entropy edge (0.993537)
 7335936       0x6FF000        Falling entropy edge (0.634517)
```

here is the result of  [Binwalk -I RDA_533.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NZfeZT2-CWYcDrwUv02ddgpFZI2QD5p3)

Here is: [.bin](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ue075GuBUPbUSjRinzjUBLDghVLsKRel) file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE! This is a VERY broad question. I'd probably start with binwalk and firmware-mod-kit and then see where that gets me. However, you give *way too little* circumstantial information for us to use our experience to give you advice.

Comment: Hi and thanks for sincerity! I'm pretty new on Reverse Engineering and it seems to me I was a little hurry to ask this question. I'll learn deeper and ask you guys meaningful question.

Comment: you may also use the "Edit" link right below your question to edit it.If it changes well for the better, some of the downvotes may also get retracted.

Comment: hi all any info about unpcaking non smart lcd board i found many chinees exe but working on my win 10 like 1
MST firmware repair tool
CVT V29&amp;amp;V39 外烧LOGO工具及说明 and MST¹Ì¼þÐÞ¸´¹¤¾ßV1.1°æ i cannot translate

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Entropy scan via `binwalk -E RDA-533.bin`

[image: RDA_533.bin binwalk entropy scan]

Step 2: Visualization via [binvis.io](http://binvis.io/#/)

[image: entropy binvis]
[image: entropy binvis 2]

Conclusion: file consists of multiple compressed or encrypted blocks interspersed with zeroes.

Step 3: look for human-readable strings via `strings -n 9 RDA_533.bin > strings.txt`

`cat -9 strings.txt | tail` shows us something interesting:

```
$ cat -n strings.txt |tail
   389  :c@W%lIQ9K
   390  >ZY#Z[$K    
   391  r5$!aVV}=
   392  ;=15ot:o,=
   393  :c@W%lIQ9K
   394  >ZY#Z[$K    
   395  r5$!aVV}=
   396  ;=15ot:o,=
   397  #codecrccheck
   398  0x586a7b76
```

Step 4: look at a hex dump via `hexdump -C RDA_533.bin > hex.txt`

`cat hex.txt | tail` shows us more about the interesting strings just discovered:

```
$ cat hex.txt | tail
00700070  c0 6a 49 6a 9a e3 06 25  c3 b5 9e 42 a9 a5 53 a0  |.jIj...%...B..S.|
00700080  c0 28 4d 4b 9a e3 06 25  c3 b5 9e 42 a9 a5 53 a0  |.(MK...%...B..S.|
*
007007f0  c0 28 4d 4b 9a e3 06 25  c3 b5 1c 43 a9 b5 17 12  |.(MK...%...C....|
00700800  5b 43 4f 44 45 5d 0a 23  63 6f 64 65 63 72 63 63  |[CODE].#codecrcc|
00700810  68 65 63 6b 0a 30 78 35  38 36 61 37 62 37 36 0a  |heck.0x586a7b76.|
00700820  0a 23 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65  0a 48 44 43 50 4b 65 79  |.#module.HDCPKey|
00700830  0a 0a 23 6d 6f 64 75 6c  65 0a 43 49 4b 65 79 0a  |..#module.CIKey.|
00700840  0a 23 45 4e 44 0a 00 00  4c 00 00 00              |.#END...L...|
0070084c
```

That should be enough to get you started.

See also: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/hdcp/v1_0/pg224-hdcp.pdf

Comment: @Ma'ruf you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you're still looking for an answer. But my best guess is that you have a firmware of a China TV/box board. In that case, download the "MStar Android TV firmware tools" and unpack the BIN file using it.

You will find the tools here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/tools-mstar-android-tv-firmware-tools-t3559227